# How to pass event from nested child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following three components. Basically I need the submit event from the CustomForm component but its' only passed to the parent component. Is there an easy way to do this? I want to avoid using an event bus.

CustomForm.vue

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <slot />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$emit('onSubmit')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

FormHolder.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CustomForm>
      <slot />
      <FormSubmit />
    </CustomForm>
  </div>
</template>
```

Page.vue

```
<template>
    <FormHolder @onSubmit="submit">
      My input fields...
    </FormHolder>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an event bus or Vuex, you need to bubble up the event so that when CustomForm emits an event, FormHolder emits an event up to Page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CustomForm @onSubmit="submit">
      <slot />
      <FormSubmit />
    </CustomForm>
  </div>
</template>
```